# what is mean by event: tag in drone.yml?

Tags: docker, build, continuous-integration, drone.io

I am going through the one of drone yml and i saw the below

```
when:
      event: tag
```

am not getting what is mean by `tag`  event , i knew push event like for example

```
when:
      event: push
      branch: master
```

means trigger the build step only when i push the code to master branch .

So can anyone explain what is mean tag even ? and when to use the tag event ?

Note : I am using git as source control

Comment: When you prepare a release you normally create a tag from your main branch. That triggers a tag event. That is merely a placeholder for a stable releasable version of your software.

Comment: create a tag from your branch , you mean creating a new branch from present branch ?

Comment: tags are not really branches. they look very much alike but you are not supposed to be working on a tag.

Answer (score 3):

In the same way that `push to master` event triggers when there is a new git push event to the master branch, the `tag` event triggers when a new git tag is added to the git repository.

It can be useful for example, when you are using git tags to mark new releases: `git tag v1.0.1`

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Drone, but this is how it behaves in similar platforms that do automatic builds and manage build pipelines.